# How to check DB2 SYSADM or SYSCTRL authorization for a user

Tags: java, db2

How to check DB2 SYSADM or SYSCTRL authorization for a user.

I need to verify user/password by means of DB2 authority to create/drop database. Is there any specific command for this?

I need to verify user/password with a command that tells whether the user has the authority to create and drop database (means attempt to validate before firing database Create command) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db2 connect
db2 get authorizations
```

Comment: Thanks @Ingo. I need to verify user/password with a command that tells whether the user has the authority to create/drop database or not. But the above commands work only with existing database, which doesn't exist in my case.

Comment: @Kishore - you can still check if the user is member of the group(s) that are configured in the instance configuration. (How to do that is OS specific, however. In UNIX, look for the id command.)

Comment: But i have no idea, how to validate user from Java code using OS specific

Comment: Yes, this is understandable, because Java does not deal with non-portable OS-Level details. Nevertheless, there is Runtime.exec

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in from unix shell, it shouldn't be to hard to adapt to the java equivalent;

```
createdb=$(db2 get authorizations|egrep 'SYSADM|SYSCTRL' | grep -c ' = YES')
if [[ $createdb ]]; then
   echo 'Do it'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this; It's implied that the ID has SELECT on the views referenced in the query below;

```
select 1 from 
sysibmadm.dbmcfg t1 join 
sysibmadm.authorizationids t2 on t1.value=t2.authid 
where t1.name='sysadm_group' fetch first row only
with ur
```

A SQL0551 on the above query would also be an indication that the connected user does not have SYSADM.

Answer (score 0):

`"GET AUTHORIZATIONS"` command is discontinued in Version 9.7.
`"AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID"` table function should be used instead.

```
db2 connect 
db2 SELECT VARCHAR(AUTHORITY, 30) AS AUTHORITY,
   D_USER,
   D_GROUP,
   D_PUBLIC,
   ROLE_USER,
   ROLE_GROUP,
   ROLE_PUBLIC,
   D_ROLE
  FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID('ALICE', 'U'))
 WHERE AUTHORITY = 'SYSADM' OR AUTHORITY = 'DBADM'
```

Link: [GET AUTHORIZATIONS command has been discontinued](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0054248.html)