# How to extract authorities from db2

Tags: database, db2, privileges

I'm developing a security product for databases in java. One feature in this product is creating security recommendations based on db-privileges and activity.

In order to do that I need to extract privilege data from db2.
So far I'v read a lot of documentation on db2 security but I haven't found a solution yet for the following problem:

The [Db2 udb security, part 4](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0601wasserman/) article explains how to extract privileges only but [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0601wasserman/#N106D0) it says:

> Instance level authority levels (SYSADM, SYSCTRL, SYSMAINT, and SYSMON) and group membership are defined outside of DB2 UDB, and are therefore not reflected in system catalog tables.

To my understanding authorities have effect on a user's privileges and therefore are crucial to get the full picture of entitlements of the db.

Further in this article it explains how to get the authorities of the connected user but doesn't explain how to get all authorities of all users\groups. similarly to this answer: [How to check DB2 SYSADM or SYSCTRL authorization for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395416/how-to-check-db2-sysadm-or-sysctrl-authorization-for-a-user)

So my question is how to extract authorities of all entities in a single query?

Comment: Is this what you are asking for: INSTANCE db2 get dbm cfg | grep GROUP DATABASE db2 "select * from syscat.DBAUTH"

Comment: No, DBAUTH specifies db privileges for grantees. I want to extract authorities which can't be found in the catalog tables.

Answer (score 1):

In DB2 for LUW there is a [table function `AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID()`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052898.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-1-3-12-2&lang=en):

```
select * from table (AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID('JOHN','U'))
```

It is available since DB2 9.7.

You would still need to access the operating system to enumerate users and groups though.